# Custom PHP snipper for email notification to the admin for pending order status in WooCommerce causing duplicated emails for processed orders

Tags: php, email, woocommerce, notifications

One of the payment methods we use on the site sets new orders to "Pending" mode which by default have no email notifications.
I've found the following snippet and added it to my child's theme functions.php file.

It does send a single email notifications for pending orders correctly, but it also causes double emails to be sent for other orders using other payment methods even though their status is "processing". How would you suggest to fix it? Thank you for your time & help.

```
// New order notification for Pending Orders
add_action( 'woocommerce_checkout_order_processed', 'pending_new_order_notification', 20, 1 );
function pending_new_order_notification( $order_id ) {

    // Get an instance of the WC_Order object
    $order = wc_get_order( $order_id );

    // Only for "pending" order status
    if( ! $order->has_status( 'pending' ) ) return;

    // Send "New Email" notification (to admin)
    WC()->mailer()->get_emails()['WC_Email_New_Order']->trigger( $order_id );
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is your use of the hook `woocommerce_checkout_order_processed`.  Instead, try `woocommerce_order_status_pending`.  I believe the rest of your code should be fine.  Basic use of this as well as some other useful hooks can be found [here](https://sarathlal.com/add-actions-based-woocommerce-order-status/).